# Redis caches the principal object issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, redis

While using the redis, I'm not able to change the user's property since Principal object is cached.

I have a service which is for changing the user's property. To do that, I've created a CustomUserDetails class and implemented the UserDetails interface. CustomUserDetails class have 2 fields; propertyid, currentPropertyid(transient). See the implementation:

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private Long propertyid;
    private Long currentPropertyid;

    public Long getPropertyid() {
        if(getCurrentPropertyid() != null){
            return getCurrentPropertyid();
        }
        return propertyid;
    }
    
    public void setPropertyid(Long propertyid) {
        this.propertyid = propertyid;
    }

    @Transient
    public Long getCurrentPropertyid() {
        return currentPropertyid;
    }
    
    public void setCurrentPropertyid(Long propertyid) {
        this.currentPropertyid = propertyid;
    }
}
```

Service implementation:

```
@PutMapping(value="change/property")
public void changeProperty(Long propertyid) {
    CustomUserDetails user = ((CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal())
    user.setCurrentPropertyid(propertyid);
}
```

So, basically service's aim is to change propertyid to see the other property's data.
This is working fine, but when I enable the redis, it is not working. Some how redis caches the Principal object. I didn't add here my redis implementation, because, in my redis implementation, I don't have any implementation that caches the UserDetails object. In any case, I've comment out the RedisTemplates that I implemented to project, but redis is not disabled, again same problem.

Any idea to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that redis caches principal object by OAuth2AccessToken. So that, I needed to override the OAuth2AccessToken. Here is my updated service method;

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customRedisTokenStore")
CustomRedisTokenStore mCustomRedisTokenStore;

@PutMapping(value="change/property")
public void changeProperty(Long propertyid) {
    CustomUserDetails user = ((CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal())
    user.setCurrentPropertyid(propertyid);
        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = mCustomRedisTokenStore.getAccessToken(oAuth2Authentication);
        mCustomRedisTokenStore.storeAccessToken(accessToken, oAuth2Authentication);
}
```